# Namespace's class's friend that is not declared and defined in the namespace

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, friend

Is it right to do so:

```
void f();

namespace ns
{
    class C
    {
        int m;
        friend void ::f();
    };
}

void f()
{
    ns::C c;
    c.m = 2;
}
```

?

The code is compiled successfully in VS. But I can't find anything about qualifying a namespace for a friend declaration in the standard. Is it even legal? Can someone provide the link or the quote from the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's legal.

A `namespace` is little more than a way of adding another layer of descrimination for functions, classes, &c..

Any function can be marked as a `friend` inside a `class`, even if that `class` is in a different `namespace` to the function. The function could be in a `namespace` too.

There's no specific section in the standard on this, but it's a corollary of the standard. This reference is a starting point: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Comment: Also, [\[class.friend\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.friend) implies it more strongly than just by not prohibiting it: Paragraph 5 discusses member functions of another class, which must use qualified-ids, and there are a number of "if unqualified" rules.